# how to load ckeditor in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, ckeditor

I have a wordpress site, and i create a box at admin area dashboard which contain a text area, and now i want my textarea implement ckeditor, does anyone knows how to do it?

here's my code snippet at themes functions.php

```
    function tresquint_news_dashboard_widget(){
     if ( $_POST['tresquint_submit_news'] ){
      $options = $_POST['tresquint_news'];
      $options['time'] = time();
      update_option('tresquint_news', $options );
      echo '<div class="updated fade"><p>Updated news.</p></div>';
     }
     $options = get_option("tresquint_news");
     ?><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p><?php _e("Enter a short news"); ?></p>
<p><label for="tresquint_news_text"><?php _e('News'); ?></label><textarea id="tresquint_news_text" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;" name="tresquint_news[text]"><?php echo $options['text']; ?></textarea></p>
<p class="submit"><input style="float: right;" type="submit" name="tresquint_submit_news" value="<?php _e('Publish'); ?>" /><div class='clear'></div></p></form><?php
    }
```

if you see on ,my code snippet above there's a text area, and i want to change that text area into ckeditor UI.

Thanks in advance
AnD

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Plugin CKEditor For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/).

I know wordpress only a little, but you can go with the [ckeditor help](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration), too:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"><p>Initial value.</p></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, I the ckeditor plugin was installed, and i was tried your workaround, but it's still doesn't work, because at the dashboard admin area, the js file for ckeditor is not loaded, so when you say: CKEDITOR.replace it'll return error because there's no such method called CKEDITOR.replace. thx for your reply